# Resize PhoneGap project with fixed image sizes

Tags: android, asp.net, ios, html, cordova

We had made a website using .Net ASP + Jquery+html5,
We want to make it running on Android and iOS, 
so we made a new UI design that suitable for iOS.

the website is made by 90% image and some text (NOT using canvas), and the width,height,x,y-axis are fixed value to suit the sizes of iOS.
I had used the Phonegap to construct apps for android and iOS, but the size cannot suitable for both of them.

Do I need to set all the values (width/height/x/y) for android?
Is there any easier method to solve in phonegap solution?
Is there any method that I can set all the values about width/height/x/y by multiple a value like 130% ?